# PHP Regular expressions -- character class

Tags: php, regex

I would like to know something about the PHP character class which I believe I do not yet fully understand. Let us take this snippet of code from w3schools.com:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "name is required";
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
            $name = "";
            $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say that the asterisk next to the closing square bracket of the third "if" condition did not exist. In other words, you would not have "zero or more times", but simply "once".

My question is then:

- if I entered a name like Jason, would I see the error message?
- Would the absence of the * symbol mean that the character class can only be matched with ONE letter?
- That is, if I simply entered J into the text field rather than Jason, would that input be printed?

I cannot test it out on w3schools.com because the source code cannot be changed by the viewer. I am instead using an online regex checker http://www.regexr.comand -- when I enter the code "/([a-zA-Z])/" and test it against the string Jason, ALL the characters match! This shouldn't be the case. I SHOULD get a false.

Comment: If you want to learn regular expressions and/or PHP you'll have to install sooner or later something to actually run code. I don't think it's possible to get purely theoretical training.

Comment: And, BTW, `^` means "start with" and `$` means "end with". That's what really makes the difference.

Comment: [`Here`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)'s a good regex tutorial where you can start learning

Comment: Enissay, that really is a good website for regex. Thank you so much. And my thanks to Alvaro as well -- you're right, I cannot understand this on pure theory alone, I have to practise it.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `^` and `$` markers your rule says "has a letter somewhere". `Jason` fulfils that.

Answer (score 1):

The `^` marker indicates "start of the string", and `$` indicates "end of the string".

Removing the asterisk means "Jason" will not match, but "J" will.

You can find the reference for the PCRE regular expression patterns in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php).

If you can't run code locally to test it, you can still run a snippet in [PHP Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/). I suggest you play with the [example patterns in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.examples.php).